# Run cron at a different frequency in specific interval

Tags: cron

I have a cron job that runs every 30 minutes, starting 10 minutes past a whole hour:

```
0+10/30+*+*+*+?
```

Now, this needs to be changed, so that in a specific time interval, it runs every 15 minutes instead. E.g. at 7.50, 8.05, 8.20 and 8.35. Then every 30 minutes again.

Is this possible with a single cron job and if so, how? Or do I need multiple jobs to accomplish this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please keep in mind that stackoverflow is not a code writting service and you should always show what you have tried by yourself.

Comment: @cronoik Thanks for the reminder. I haven't tried anything, as I have no idea how to go about this in a single cron job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not easy in a single cron, and that is also hard to read.

multiple jobs may work fine and show much clear

```
// This will start at 1:10am, and every 30minutes run once.
0+10/30+1-23/2+*+*+?
// This will start at 0:10am, and every 15minutes run once.
0+10/15+0-24/2+*+*+?
```

you may also consider to void the two job running at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've understood, this is not possible within a single cron job. 
[setup cron from morning to evening only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13136706/setup-cron-from-morning-to-evening-only) points out that three different cron jobs are needed, so I am closing my question.